# php data between two dates for specific person

Tags: javascript, php, html

i retrieve data between two dates but the problem is to retrieve data between two dates for specific person so for i used this this is working perfectly when i only retrieve data between dates but did not work when i use dphone means for specific doctor phone number

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM checker WHERE date between '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND dphone='$splist'"
```

i want to retrieve data where dphone match any suggestion please so i can retrieve data according to my need

Comment: What's the value of your `$splist`?

Comment: its a mobile number like i have appointments for specific doctors in different dates so $splist is basically a mobile number

Comment: Does the query work when you type the values manually?

Comment: yes its works but only if i retrieve over all dates between some specific criteria and exclude the dphone=$splist

Comment: but i want to fetch dates for specific doctor thats why i added dphone=$splist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM checker WHERE dphone='$splist' AND date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'
```

Also, are you sure the value in the "dphone" field for the doctor you're trying to get, matches $splist exactly?

Comment: :) i did that before you post it here and worked perfectly but thank and answer accepted . . .

Comment: i dont know exactly why its works in this order but may be after between BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' its takes  dphone='$splist' as third date . .which is not date but dont know exaclty

Comment: the sql BETWEEN operator acts a bit weird sometimes compared to other operators, but I believe(don't quote me :P) you can also accomplish it by adding a comma after the last date. However, personally, i went with the above approach because it was pretty much a sure thing to work.